# Different result after run command between shell script and terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, sh, amazon-ecr

### Situation

Use shell script to push docker images (Nodejs app) to ECR

### Command

`aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-southeast-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`

### File shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

docker build -t abc/abc-api ../../abc/abc-api

docker build -t abc/abc-fe ../../abc/abc-fe

aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-southeast-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

docker tag abc/abc-api xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/abc:api-latest

docker push xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/abc:api-latest

docker tag abc/abc-fe xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/abc:fe-latest

docker push xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/abc:fe-latest
```

### Current

- When run file shell script

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

- When run command on terminal

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/***/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

### What I want

Shell script login succeeded

### Environment

- Linux mint 20
- aws-cli 2.0.46
- Configured aws authentication by `aws configure`

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "sell script" and "terminal"?

Comment: I have just update file shell script and some description

Comment: When do you execute your shell script?

Comment: Maybe you need to explicitly set your profile in the script, e.g. `aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-southeast-1 --profile <YOUR_AWS_PROFILE_TO_USE> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: I use shell script for deployment. I push docker images to ECR and use EB (Multi-images docker environment) to build from ECR

Comment: @Marcin it still have that error

Comment: So you run the script in your computer? Not some container or ec2 instance?

Comment: Yessssssssssssss

Comment: What about going back to basic. Can you run from shell script, the simplest commands, such as `aws s3 ls`? No docker, no other clutter. Just the most basic command.

Comment: `Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".` This is what I received

Comment: And you sure that you use same user as in terminal? Not sudo or a different user than yourself?

Comment: My linux has only 1 user

Comment: can you add `whoami` into the script and check if you are actually excuting the script under your own user, not root.

Comment: It show root...

Comment: So you are using different user then yourself when you run the command in terminal. This explains why it does not work.

Comment: Oh. I understood. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. I will provide an answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: Of course!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The reason why the script does not work is that it is **executed under root user**. The root user does not have aws profile defined, which explain why the script errors out with "You can configure credentials by running "aws configure" message.

To rectify the issue, there are some posibilites:

1. Don't run the script under root user. Run it as your own user, because you have aws profile configure for yourself (preferred).
2. Create new aws profile for the root user.